# How to get progress bar like android chrome's

Tags: android

How do I get a progress bar like the one in chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

then

```
setProgress(value);
```

Value must be in the range 0 - 10000;

Comment: I think so (since this exists from API level 1, way before the Action Bar was introduced). But I haven't tested it.

Comment: This feature is now deprecated and no longer supported from API 21.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed this some time ago . It is just a class that will work just like chrome web browser loader. 
Lets try it . Hope you will like it.

Please follow below post.

http://codecops.blogspot.in/2017/09/chrome-like-progressbar-in-android.html

OR see the code below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/** * created by PARAMBIR SINGH on 22/9/17. */
public class PKromeProgressBar extends LinearLayout
{
    private View progressiveView, supportiveView;
    private int progressColor;
    private int maxProgress = 100;

    /**     * HOW TO USE {@link PKromeProgressBar}     * Never user height = wrap_content     * initialize view just like other views     * See methods documentations to know their use     */    public PKromeProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initProgressBar();
    }

    public PKromeProgressBar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initProgressBar();
    }

    public PKromeProgressBar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initProgressBar();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public PKromeProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initProgressBar();
    }

    /**     * this method must be called from constructor : USER DONT NEED TO DO ANYTHING WITH THIS     */    private void initProgressBar() {
        progressColor = getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black);

        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        progressiveView = new View(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10);
        progressiveView.setLayoutParams(params);
        progressiveView.setBackgroundColor(progressColor);

        supportiveView = new View(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        supportiveView.setLayoutParams(params2);

        this.addView(progressiveView);
        this.addView(supportiveView);

        this.setWeightSum(maxProgress);
    }

    /**     * pass your current progress that need to set on the progressbar     *     * @param progress     */    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, progress);
        progressiveView.setLayoutParams(params);

        this.setVisibility(progress < maxProgress ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
    }

    /**     * Pass id of the color that you want to use for progressbar     *     * @param color     */    public void setProgressColor(int color) {
        progressColor = color;
        progressiveView.invalidate();
    }


    /**     * Pass the max progress you want to set...     * By Default it is 100     *     * @param maxProgress     */    public void setMaxProgress(int maxProgress) {
        this.maxProgress = maxProgress;
        this.invalidate();
        progressiveView.invalidate();
        supportiveView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

HOW TO USE:

In xml layout file .place anywhere inbetween other views.

```
<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE.PKromeProgressBar    android:id="@+id/pkProgressBar"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="2dp"/>
```

In your Activity or Fragment use the below code

```
PKromeProgressBar pkProgressBar;

pkProgressBar = (PKromeProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pkProgressBar);
```

Methods that can be used further in java code

```
setProgress(progress); // Send any integer value between 0 to maxProgress

setProgressColor(colorId); // By Default it is Black

setMaxProgress(maxProgress); // By Default it is 100
```